# Existence of a non constant analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ is non-constant analytic function. Which of the following are possible:

> i. $|f(z)|=1\ \forall\ z\ s.t. 0 < |z|<\frac{1}{2}$

> ii. $f(z)=0$ for infinitely many z such that $0 < |z|<\frac{1}{2}$

> iii. $f(z)\in \mathbb{R}\  \forall\ z\ s.t. 0 < |z|<\frac{1}{2}$

> iv. $|f(z)| < |z|\ \forall z\ s.t.0 < |z|<\frac{1}{2}$

ii. is false as $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is a set with limit point and hence by identity theorem $f$ is constant.

iii. is false as $f$ is open map and $f(0<|z|<\frac{1}{2})$ is not open.

What about i. and iv?
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: for 1st one use Cauchy Riemann equations

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't really get your hint.

Comment: (iii) you don't know that's closed, you know it is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i. $|f|$ attains its maximum value of the disk of radius $\frac 1  2$ around $0$. By MMP $f$ is a constant $c$ on this disk. This implies that it is a  constant on $\mathbb D$ also. [Apply Identity Theorem to $f-c$].

1v. $f(z)=\frac z 2$ satisfies this inequality.

Comment: but how do I know that 1 is the maximum value. Why it can't be more than 1?

Comment: sorry I made an error in the last option. It's strict inequality.

Comment: @Naman That make little difference. Just divide by $2$.

Comment: yeah...that's fine...but I didnt follow i.

Comment: Do you know MMP (Maximum Modulus Principle)?  @Naman

Comment: understood....thank u

Answer (score 1):

For first one:

If you consider $f = u + iv$ then first condition implies that $u^2 + v^2=1$ then by partial differentiation we have
$$
u_xu+v_xv = 0
$$
and
$$
u_yu+v_yv=0
$$

Now use Cauchy Riemann equations $u_x = v_y $ and $u_y = -v_x$ and get a contradiction.

Third one also very easy to do with the help of C-R equations. Observe that third condition implies that $v=0$ and consequently $v_x = v_y = 0$. Further by C-R equations we have $u_x = u_y =0$ which would imply that $u=0$ and ofcourse this is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your A to (iii) is right but your reason is wrong. If $f$ is not constant on $E=\{z:0<|z|<1/2\}$ then its image is non-empty and open in $\Bbb C$ (as you said), but no non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb C.$

Another way, with Re$(f)=u$ and Im$(f)=v.$ If $v$ is $0$ on $E$ then  $u_x=u_x+iv_x=f'=-iu_y+v_y=-iu_y,$ so $f'$ is both real and imaginary so $f'=0$ on $E$. And $E$ is a connected open set. So $f$ is constant on $E$.

Comment: thanks...I made the changes.